# How can I remove this large 'gap' with the 'description section, without actually removing the needed description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to figure this out all day but have reached my code knowledge limit as I try to change the child theme to achieve this.

Here's an image showing what my site currently displays, next to an image of the desired result.

[What I have VS What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFs2H.jpg)

I've tried using a few snippets of code I've found on the Stack Exchange that remove Woocommerce descriptions but with no luck. I'd like to remove the gap, the description title, but must keep the description box itself because that's what allows the tabs at the bottom of the page.

Here's a link to the page itself, I can find and isolate the gap and fix it using the html, but I've no idea how that relates to the CSS (I'm new to this) Link : https://folduptoys.com/product/space-garden-playset/

Here's how it's currently set up, I'm using the Salient theme, with the 'Product Tab Position' set to 'Fullwidth Under Images'.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you x

-Alex

Answer (score 0):

Here's what will work but it's important to note that if other tabs show up, like 'Attributes' or 'Dimensions' that they'll be visible, but the `Description' tab won't be.  So you'll have to consider whether you want it to work that way or not.

There's two things going on, first, the margins on the tab menu were big. 70px on top and 50px on the bottom.  Seems too large in my opinion but I long ago gave up guessing on why Salient's devs do anything.

The second thing is to hide the 'Description' tab.  If other tabs end up being present though, they'll show up in it's place.

```
div.product .woocommerce-tabs .full-width-content[data-tab-style="fullwidth"] ul.tabs{
     margin:0 auto;
}
#tab-title-description{
     display:none;
}
```

If what you want is to entirely remove the tabs navigation, meaning that if other tabs are there, no one will be able to see/access them, so not a good idea unless you're also modifying the tab content layout so that they all display, then use this to hid that whole bar.

```
div.product .woocommerce-tabs .full-width-content[data-tab-style="fullwidth"] ul.tabs{
     display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony Djukic, **thank you so much** for trying to help me! 

Just so I understand, is there a way for me to alter the 70px and 50px margins on the menu tabs?
 I've been trying to find a way to get this to work on the child theme but it's a bit beyond my level. 

I'm probably doing something wrong, but when I put the code you supplied into the Stylesheet nothing seemed to change.

-Alex :)